# Transition: width not working in Firefox

Tags: css

I am adding a class to an hr element that grows when it has this class. It is working nicely in chrome but not on firefox. I have inspected and it is adding the class so the css is not working.

Any ideas?

```
hr.portfolio-line {
width: 0px;
background-color: #fff;
border: none;
height: 2px;
z-index: 8;
position: relative;
}
hr.portfolio-line.grow {
-webkit-transition: width 1s ease-out;
-moz-transition: width 1s ease-out;
-o-transition: width 1s ease-out;
transition:  width 1s ease-out;
width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle showing this? - I wonder why you are using an `<hr>` what happens if you replace the `<hr>` with a `<div>` or `<span>`

Comment: It works for me both in chrome and FF: https://jsfiddle.net/odvfqbf1/

Comment: works for me too on FF and Chrome. How are you applying the class?

Comment: Ok.. seems to be working on jsfiddle so must be something else going wrong. not sure what though :D haha.. thanks for your time.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/peterdouglas/qczknywn/